# Heroku + Discord.py Deployed but never came online

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I was working on my discord bot today, and uploading it to heroku.  I did everything my tutorial said to do, but when I flicked the deploy switch on the bot stayed offline.  Has this problem happened to anyone else? Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: BTW this is my tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvg9bndP1U

Answer (score 0):

His tutorial needs to be updated because it contains the incorrect way to list the discord.py library dependency. To fix your issue, you need to remove the `@rewrite` in the Github link in your `requirements.txt` file. However, instead of removing the `@rewrite`, just specify the discord version. Replace your `requirements.txt` file with the following:

```
discord.py==1.6.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pandas
dnspython==1.16.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have clicked 'confirm' after clicking the switch you mentioned in the resources tab.
2. Make sure `Procfile`'s first letter (P) is uppercase.
3. Make sure `requirements.txt` has the correct credentials. (You can get the version of modules you are using by doing `pip freeze` on your terminal)
4. Make sure you have entered your bot token in config vars
5. If the bot still doesn't come online then goto `applications -> more -> View logs` to see if worker raised any errors.